# CoordinatorLayout and pinned views

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to build a UI that uses CoordinatorLayout with 2 views that when scrolled enough get pinned and remain on top of everything goes under them. This is the ASCII kinda way where AAAA is the first view (rectangle), BBBB is the second view, ..... is an image with parallax effect and ;;;; is just text within NestedScroll. I experimented with CoordinatorLayout but no luck yet.

Example:

```
State 1    State 2
---------- ----------
AAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA
.......... BBBBBBBBBB
.......... ;;;;;;;;;;
.......... ;;;;;;;;;;
BBBBBBBBBB ;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;; ;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;
```